# -webkit-transform Rotation Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, rotation, rotatetransform

Ok, I've looked at virtually all of the rotation entries on this site and just cannot solve this.  It has been 3 full days of trying to figure it out.  More than likely it is something very simple but I just cannot get it.   Here's the issue:  I have 2 images that have rotate controls.  However, when I go to rotate 1, they both rotate.  I want them not to rotate simultaneously, but rather, on their own.  You can see it here:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11770605/sample2.html

Here's the following code for main.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ $('.cc-element').rotatable(); });
```

and here's the markup:

```
    <span id="cc-element-1" class="cc-element ui-draggable cc-active" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);" ><image goes here></span>
```

I've also tried:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cc-element').rotatable();
    $('.cc-element2').rotatable();
    });
```

and

```
    <span id="cc-element-2" class="cc-element ui-draggable cc-active" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);" > <image goes here>< /span>
```

but that modification did NOT work.  Please, help me, I MUST get this fixed asap.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your "rotatable()" plugin operates on the `this` value passed to it, which when your selector is ".cc-element" will be a **list** of both elements.  Thus, your calls to the "roll()" plugin operate on the whole list.

You need to wrap appropriate code in that plugin in an "each()" iterator. Something like:

```
    $.fn.rotatable = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          // ... the rest of the plugin, as it is now ...
      });
    };
```

Comment: i tried this suggestion and the one above but BOTH remove the controls from the images and now, neither can be rotated!

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting the elements by class and they both have the same class. Change it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cc-element').rotatable();
    $('#cc-element2').rotatable();
    });
```

Comment: The "rotatable()" plugin would still be broken, however; it should work the way he originally set up the page.

Comment: this did not do the trick.  in fact, it made the controls disappear altogether!